# What can I conclude from this inequality?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, quadratics

I was solving an equation and reached this inequality
$$t^2−1≤\sin^2\alpha$$

- What conclusions can I draw about $t$ from the above inequality (given that $\alpha \in \mathbb R$)?
- Is it correct to use the minimum value of RHS (zero) and proceed?

Here's the complete context of the question:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the minimum value of $\sin^2 \alpha$ is $0$, this means that for any real $t$ in $-1 ≤ t ≤ 1$, the inequality will hold regardless of the value of $\alpha$.

Similarly, the maximum value of $\sin^2 \alpha$ is $1$. This means that for any $t$ that satisfy $t < -\sqrt{2}$ or $t > \sqrt{2}$, the inequality will *not* hold regardless of $\alpha$.

Now you can relate this back to the range of the function.

Comment: That's what I had thought, but the actual answer is: $−√2≤t≤-1 ⋃ 1≤t≤√2$
Please take a look at the link in the question. I don't know what's going wrong.

Comment: Your solution must be correct then. When $\alpha =0$, we have the equation $f(x) = \left( \sin x + \sqrt{\sin^2 x} \right) \cos x$. Then $f(0) = 0$ so the suggested answer is wrong.

Comment: Also here is how to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). In particular \sqrt{x} is $\sqrt{x}$ and \bigcup is $\bigcup$.